# ALSA - Codec Registration

Tags: alsa

My Codec is registered after SOC init is done. In SOC init, ALSA cannot find codec registered and hence defer the sound card registration. Later when I register codec, its entry is not registered in /proc/asound/pcm and also codec is not probed.

I am using Kernel version 3.4.0 with OMAP panda.

Thanks